# Magnific popup has scroll problems on the iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, magnific-popup

I'm using the Magnific popup for to show the popup in my site, it's worked well in all browsers and smartphones, however it happened a problem on the iPhone, when I scroll the page with popup open, the "body" scroll together.

This is my jQuery code:

```
if ($.fn.magnificPopup) {
    $('.open-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        alignTop: true,
        midClick: true,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'modulos-popup fade-popup'
    });
    $.extend(true, $.magnificPopup.defaults, {
      tClose: 'Fechar (Esc)',
      tLoading: 'Carregando...'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yeah I'm facing the same problem seems like the following patch is working for me:

utils.js(useful if you are using the popup in different places)

```
window.Utils = {
  magnificPopupConfiguration: function() {
    var startWindowScroll = 0;

    return {
      beforeOpen: function() {
        startWindowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('html').addClass('mfp-helper');
      },
      close: function() {
        $('html').removeClass('mfp-helper');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('body').animate({ scrollTop: startWindowScroll }, 0);
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

css:

```
.mfp-wrap {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

html.mfp-helper {
  height: 100%;

  body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  }
}
```

Preparing the js:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

      if ($('.open-popup-link').length) {
        startWindowScroll = 0;
        $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
          type: 'inline',
          midClick: true,
          fixedContentPos: true,
          callbacks: Utils.magnificPopupConfiguration()
        });
      }
   });
```

html:

```
   <a class="open-popup-link" href="#your-html-content">text link</a>
```

Comment: For me only `$('html').animate({ scrollTop: startWindowScroll }, 0);` worked